# Best practices for multiple upload fields

Tags: php, html, forms

Yes, I know there are a lot of threads around this topic but I'm not here specifically for troubleshooting. I'm looking for best practices or suggestions.

I have a form on which I've separated out different spots to allow users to submit up to 4 images + a description about each. So that looks like

```
<div class="container" style="margin-left:0px; padding-left:0px;">
<div class="form-group row" style="margin-left:0px;">

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
<label for="safetyHazard1_notes"><strong>Safety observation 1:</strong></label>  <input type="file" name="safetyHazard1" id="safetyHazard1" value=""><br /> <br />
<textarea cols="25" rows="3" id="safetyHazard1_notes" name="safetyHazard1_notes" placeholder="Enter notes for this observation" ></textarea> </div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
<label for="safetyHazard2_notes"><strong>Safety observation 2:</strong></label> <input type="file" name="safetyHazard2" id="safetyHazard2" value=""><br /><br />
<textarea cols="25" rows="3" id="safetyHazard2_notes" name="safetyHazard2_notes" placeholder="Enter notes for this observation" ></textarea> </div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
<label for="safetyHazard3_notes"><strong>Safety observation 3:</strong></label> <input type="file" name="safetyHazard3" id="safetyHazard3" value=""><br /><br />
<textarea cols="25" rows="3" id="safetyHazard2_notes" name="safetyHazard2_notes" placeholder="Enter notes for this observation" ></textarea> </div>

<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
<label for="other_notes"><strong>Other observations:</strong></label> <input type="file" name="otherObservation" id="otherObservation" value=""><br /><br />
<textarea cols="25" rows="3" id="other_notes" name="other_notes" placeholder="Enter notes for this observation" ></textarea> </div>
</div></div>
```

Now for the form processing I've got the first one of these upload fields functioning and this is where I'm asking for this communities help. Here is my PHP on for the form processing.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$target_dir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/testing/tim/uploads/';
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["safetyHazard1"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["safetyHazard1"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["safetyHazard1"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["safetyHazard1"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["safetyHazard1"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

For the first one, everything is working as expected - file is being uploaded to my specified directory and my database is storing the file name as uploaded by the user. GREAT!

BUT now when I move on to the remaining 3 uploads, what is the best practice here? I can obviously copy this code multiple times and then rename variables such as `target_dir` to `target_dir1, target_dir2, etc`. Or is there a trick that will allow me to utilize my PHP code one time with something like `safetyHazard[*]`. Does that make sense?

Comment: You can create `function` for upload and just call it in `for` loop with parameters such as `target_dir` for example

Comment: `I'm not here specifically for troubleshooting. I'm looking for best practices or suggestions.` [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) may be a bit more relevant for this criteria.

Comment: first time I've ever seen Code Review Stack Exchange - thank you.

@xAqweRx, good suggestion - I'll give this a try

Comment: Use arrays in html so that you can loop over all your uploads in php: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php example #3